# How to duplicate HTML templates with different contents (text, picture)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website where I am going to use the same template for a lot of the same pages, only the text and picture needs to be changed. The only thing that is different from the different pages are the different sports, so I have a jumbotron picture that I want to change, as well as the text about the sport itself. I am wondering if there is any smart ways of doing this instead of making a .html file for every page?

Comment: stack is not about doing everything for you. Please share with us what you have done so far

Comment: It sounds like you are new to this. Changing contents dynamically usually requires [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XHR_(XMLHttpRequest)), but your question is not very specific.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some file-hosting services allow for a base HTML template, but usually, you will need to create a HTML file for every page on a site. If you use Adobe Muse, for example, it will output the code with the least amount of white-space and with the most efficient size possible. But it will still output multiple HTML pages.

TLDR: You will need to make a HTML document for each page on your site, usually.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.
Don't use css in that page itself. Create another page containing only css codes and name it as "css.css" and place the file in same folder in which the html file is present.

Then use external link for css. Insert the code given below in the head part of the html document.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

consider to use some templates instead of using plain html.
if you are doing server-side rendering then there are a lot of frameworks you can use for each language.Just google popular framework for the backend language you are using.

For frontend side you can use some Single page application framework for example angular, react, vue or something like handlebars. check them and pick one